# Calculating exact age as on a specified date

Tags: logic

The birth date (day, month and year) is given. How to calculate the exact age (days, months and years) on a specified date?

Comment: By subtraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating the days elapsed is more of an algorithm of sorts, but the easiest way I'd say would be to do this:

1) Start with your date d/m/y, where the three variables stand for day, month, and year (duh).

2) Calculate the amount of days to the start of the next month (if d=1, ignore this). Depending on the month, this could be $29-d$ days (if typical february), $30-d$ days (if leap year february), $31-d$ days (if 30-day month), or $32-d$ days (if 31-day month).

3) Calculate the amount of months until New Year's day next year. This should be $12-m,$ where m is the current month (unless d=1, in which case it's $13-m$).

4) Calculate the amount of years until the start of the year of the end date.

5) Add on the amount of months and days from the start of the final date year until the desired date.

6) Do any necessary carry-overs.

---

Here's an example:

Let's compute the amount of days, months, and years between 13/11/2015 and 12/8/2017 (including the start and end).

First, we compute the amount of days until the beginning of the next month after November 13th, which in this case is 18 days.

Then, we compute the amount of months until the beginning of the next year after December 1st, which in this case is a single month.

Now, from 1/1/2016 to 1/1/2017, there is exactly one year.

From 1/1/2017 to 12/8/2017, there are 8 months and 12 days.

This gives a total count of 1 year, 9 months, and 30 days.

---

Note that you should be careful with month/day overlap; "30 days" could mean a month or not, depending on the month in context.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is way too simple. Whatever be the given birth year, just get the approximate age in years from whatever is the year today. Then do the same for months and days.

For example,

If you are given a birth date: $21$ January, $1998$ and you want to calculate the age today ($6$ October, $2017$).

$2017-1998 = 19$ years.

October $-$ January $= 10 - 1 = 9$ months.

Now, these $9$ months will be exactly completed on the $21^{st}$ of October. Therefore, the days which we missed are $21 - 6 = 15$.

Therefore, there were $15$ days left for the $9$ months to complete.

Considering a month to be of averagely $30$ days, the final age would be $19$ years, $8$ months and $15$ days.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who sufficiently dabbled with programming will be painfully aware of the quirks that come with any date/time related issue. Since you want to know the *exact* age, we need to be very careful. In particular, we need to account for all [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) that have occurred in the relevant time frame.

Fortunately, since this is such a major pain, computer scientist early on came up with a solution to this problem: [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Unix time is simply the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 on 1970-01-01, the first of January in 1970 - including all leap seconds.

The easiest way to calculate the exact age of someone is to take the current Unix time and substract the Unix time of their birth. This will give their age in seconds which now can be converted easily back into your desired format of time. (There are a few complications if the person happens to be born prior to 1970 - we basically lose track of leap seconds.)

To get the Unix time, simply use a [Unix time converter](https://unixtime.guru/) of your choice.